# Change colour of highlighted text of a textbox in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I want to have a button that changes the selected/highlighted text of a TextBox in PowerPoint VBA.
I know how to change all the text on a TextBox, but not the selected/highlighted.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Show the code you have already and what you've tried and what it does that doesn't suit your liking

Comment: Thing is I can't... I don't know how to make text selected coloured in a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to ensure that there's a current selection and that the selection is text before trying to change anything:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection
    If .Type = ppSelectionText Then  ' Text is selected
        ' Make it green, for example:
        .TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
End With
```